# how to find where the variable is modified

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

I have a variable `join` in a page whose value is either `true` or `false`.

When I run the page, how can I know which method modified the variable using the debug tool in chrome?

Comment: what do you mean which method , please be more specific , provide a code or fiddle.

Comment: you can use a getter/setter and log arguments.callee.caller in the setter

Comment: or just set a breakpoint or watch in the devtools sources pane

Answer (score 0):

Use the `debugger` keyword in your code.  This is the equivalent of setting a breakpoint in a debugger.  When the browser hits the `debugger` the program will stop and you can inspect the stack trace from the dev tools.

Read [this](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) on debugging javascript.